# Unable to mock instance attribute while leveraging side_effect

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

I am trying to perform something similar to this:

```
mymock = Mock()
mymock.variable.side_effect = [1,2,3]
print mymock.variable # Should print 1
print mymock.variable # Should print 2
print mymock.variable # Should print 3
```

However, I am not getting the desired outcome.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Using `side_effect` only applies when the attribute is called as a method:

```
In [3]: mymock = Mock()

In [4]: mymock.variable.side_effect = [1,2,3]

In [5]: mymock.variable()
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: mymock.variable()
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: mymock.variable()
Out[7]: 3
```

There is no similar functionality for assigning a value to the an attribute.

Comment: Is there some way to achieve this without using side_effect?